# CLLocation is not nil but trying to print it out throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, gps, exc-bad-access, cllocation, core-location

Sorry, this may be a noob question but I'm working with CoreLocation and this has be stumped.

I'm looking up the currentLocation using a singleton that was recommended on this site and when I get the currentLocation object, it returns true to a not nil check.  However, when I try to print out its description, it throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
//WORKS Current location 8.6602e-290
NSLog(@"Current location %g",currLoc);

//DOESN'T WORK
NSLog(@"Current location %@",[currLoc description]);

//DOESN'T WORK - Is this causing the description to fail as well?
NSLog(@"Current location %g",currLoc.coordinate.latitude);
```

Why am I able to see something on the first one but not the others?  BTW, this is being run on a 3.1.2 simulator Thanks.

Comment: did you ever solve this? I am seeing this too, whenever I access the properties latitude or longitude...

Answer (score 1):

currLoc.coordinate.latitude is type double... you can use %f if %g is not working

```
NSLog(@"Current location %f",currLoc.coordinate.latitude);
```

Comment: That also throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Answer (score 0):

**currLoc** might be returning **TRUE** for **not Nil check**. But there may be **chances of having freed object(Dangling pointer)** which will pass the nil check condition. This might be you problem.

Instead of using the **currLoc member directly, use Accessor for currLoc**. This will fix your problem :)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear.  currLoc is actually a local variable that I'm setting in this controller but it's set to locationController.currentLocation.   LocationController is the interface implementing CLLocationManagerDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

```
// malformed: %g format specifier expects type
// double, you're passing an objc object.
// sending arguments through (...) with the
// invalid types/widths is a near certain way
// to crash an app, and the data will be useless
// to the function called (NSLog in this case)
NSLog(@"Current location %g",currLoc);

// try running the app with zombies enabled.
// in short, enabling zombies (NSZombiesEnabled)
// is a debugging facility to determine whether
// you use an objc object which would have been freed.
NSLog(@"Current location %@",[currLoc description]);

// as long as currLoc is a pointer to a valid (non-freed)
// objc object, then this should be fine. if it is not valid
NSLog(@"Current location %g",currLoc.coordinate.latitude);
```

Comment: I guess my question was in what situations could currLog pass a nil check and still throw an error while trying to access currLoc.coordinate.latitude.  I was checking the currLoc to make sure that it was being set to some value by LocationManager and I was able to get around the problem by add some BOOL var whose sole purpose is to track the setting of that variable.  Thanks for the input.   ps. I usually have NSZombie enabled while doing any testing and I didn't see anything helpful while trying to debug this.  T